# I can't get all the decimal part when dividing in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, decimal

I'm facing some weird behavior from db2 when I'm dividing, the result doesn't contain all the decimal numbers that I was expecting as if its rounded to 5th decimal place always.

Example

```
SELECT 
dec(dec(1040,4,0)/dec(9,1,0),16,13) as sample
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Result

```
    SAMPLE              
--------------------
115.55556
```

From the code above, I'm expecting **115.5555555555556**  as the result. Just like what the calculator is giving me.

Thanks,
Erwin

Comment: What platform & version of DB2?  On DB2 for i 7.2, I get 115.5555555555555 for your statement.  Also, what tool are you using to run the statement?

Comment: Thanks for giving me idea. The tool is the culprit in my problem extending squirrel to display 20 dec or set local saved the day for me.

Answer (score 0):

Does increasing the scale and precision on inner `DEC` work? For example:

```
SELECT 
dec(dec(1040,16,13)/dec(9,16,13),16,13) as sample
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules for the precision and scale of decimal division are . . . let's use the adjective "arcane".  The documentation does attempt an [explanation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_decimaldivision.html).

Basically, I would advise you just to increase the scale and precision.  You might as well start with the values you are aiming for:

```
SELECT dec(dec(1040, 20, 13) / dec(9, 20, 13), 16, 13) as sample
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

I changed the scale of the first value to 20 because 16 is not big enough with 13 decimal points.